# How can I change a string in a cell with my pre-made dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big dataset (pandas df). It's about news reading. I'm trying to clean it. But it's a bit messy.  I want to work on coutries but in some (most!) rows it has the city name not the country. I created a dict, keys are countries and values are cities. I want to change city names to country names. I

To picture the data frame (I have 1 m rows btw):

```
   Country      Age
0  France      25-34
1  Lyon        45-54
2  Kiev        35-44
3  France      25-34
4  New York    25-34
5  Paris        65+
6  Toulouse    35-44
7  Nice        55-64
8  Chicago     45-54
9  Stuttgart   35-44
10 Germany      65+
11 Moscow      25-34
12 USA         45-54
13 Italy       35-44
14 Berlin       65+
15 Russia      25-34
16 Ukraine     45-54
17 Lille       35-44
18 Germany      65+
19 Moscow      25-34
20 Lviv        25-34
21 Vladivostok 25-34
22 Rome        25-34
23 Milan       25-34
```

My checklist;

```
checklist = {"France":["Touluse","Lyon","Paris","Nice","Lille"],"USA":["New York","Chicago"],"Germany":["Berlin","Stuttgart"],"Ukraine":["Lviv","Kiev"],"Russia":["Moscow",Vladivostok],"Italy":["Rome","Milan"]}
```

Comment: Well, because you want to map cities to countries, I'd do it the other way around - create a dict with cities as keys and the corresponding country as value. Yes, the dict would become much larger and might look very redundant, but on the other hand, it would make things easier.

Comment: And maybe it doesn't matter, but remember that especially the US likes to name cities after cities in other countries (see this list as an example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._places_named_after_non-U.S._places), so the mapping isn't disambiguous.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written the code what @Tobias suggested in the comments.

```
cities, countries = [],[]

for key, value in checklist.items():
  for i in value:
    cities.append(i)
    countries.append(key)

new_checklist = dict(zip(cities,countries))
```

The above inverts your checklist. You can then change rows like this

```
df['country'] = df['country'].apply(lambda x: new_checklist[x] if x in new_checklist.keys() else x)
```

Comment: second one returns a KeyError: 'city' . There is no column called city. Am i missing something?

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. I have edited my answer.